# Javascript code is not catching null value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really new to javascript and I'm trying to prevent a textbox from accepting letters and empty values. This is what I have:

```
function checkInp()
{
var x=document.forms["newPerson"]["ThisBox"].value;
    if (isNaN(x) || is_null(x)) 
    {
        alert("This box can only contain numeric values");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my form tag:

```
<form name="newPerson" action="newPerson2.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkInp();">
```

This DOES prevent letters from passing through, but it DOES NOT prevent empty values from going through.

Comment: Remember undefined is not === null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check like this

```
if(!x || isNaN(x)){
  alert("This box can only contain numeric values");
  return false;
}
```

In javascript `"",null,undefined,NaN,0` all consider `false`.

Comment: I recommend this approach as well. This is called ````falsey```` meaning "Something which evaluates to FALSE." Read more: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/